# Enable mod_xsendfile only for subdirectory

Tags: httpd, apache-2.4

I'm trying to enable xsendfile only for the `/var/www/wsgi/site/priv` subdirectory.
With the configuration below my site is serving 0 byte files which apparently means that xsendfile is not correctly enabled.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/wsgi/site

    WSGIDaemonProcess site user=site group=site python-path=/usr/local/site:/usr/local/virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup site
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/wsgi/site/wsgi.py

    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>

    # ... some alias for static files ...

    Alias /priv/ /var/www/wsgi/site/priv/
    <Directory /var/www/wsgi/site/priv>
        Require all denied
        XSendFile On
        XSendFilePath /var/www/wsgi/site/priv/jobfiles
        # ^ I know that this is a different path. 
        # I only need access to that subfolder for now.
    </Directory>

    # ... logging conf ...

</VirtualHost>
```

xsendfile's docs say that the directives are allowed in a `<Directory>` so...

What is wrong?

Comment: I tried to tag this with `mod-xsendfile` but I don't have enough reputation.